# Failed to launch renderer:Exception For HTML5 to PDF Convertor

Tags: node.js

I am using "html5-to-pdf" module to convert HTML5 page to PDF.Below is the code snippet I am using for specifying the Input and Output files.

```
var html5pdf = require("html5-to-pdf");
var fs = require("fs");
fs.createReadStream("/Vineet/POC/HTML_Inputs/TestSample.html")
 .pipe(html5pdf())
 .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/Vineet/POC/PDF_Outputs/Output.pdf"));
```

While executing this code I am getting below exception:

```
Error: Failed to launch renderer
  at C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\html5-to-pdf\src\phantom.coffee:55:35
  at Proto.apply (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\dnode-protocol\index.js:123:13)
  at Proto.handle (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\dnode-protocol\index.js:99:19)
  at D.dnode.handle (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\dnode\lib\dnode.js:140:21)
  at D.dnode.write (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\dnode\lib\dnode.js:128:22)
  at SockJSConnection.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at SockJSConnection.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at Session.didMessage (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\sockjs\lib\transport.js:220:25)
  at WebSocketReceiver.didMessage (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\sockjs\lib\trans-websocket.js:102:40)
  at C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\sockjs\lib\trans-websocket.js:75:22
  at .<anonymous> (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\faye-websocket\lib\faye\websocket\api\event_target.js:41:7)
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\faye-websocket\lib\faye\websocket\api\event_target.js:40:33)
  at API.receive (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\faye-websocket\lib\faye\websocket\api.js:30:10)
  at instance._emitFrame (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\faye-websocket\lib\faye\websocket\hybi_parser.js:285:44)
  at instance.parse (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\faye-websocket\lib\faye\websocket\hybi_parser.js:143:18)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Vineet\POC\node_modules\faye-websocket\lib\faye\websocket.js:72:33)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
  at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:542:20)
```

Due to which The PDF generated is of 0 bytes and is not being able to open.CAn any one help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: "Html-Pdf" package is working for me . But I want to use  "html5-to-pdf" package only because in my project We are using HTML5 pages.

Answer (score 0):

This package need [PhatomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) installed on your computer. Phantomjs renders the page and saves it to a PDF. Read [html5-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html5-to-pdf)  **options** params

You should use [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) package instead.

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf'),
    fs = require('fs');

pdf.create(fs.readFileSync('./Vineet/POC/HTML_Inputs/TestSample.html', 'utf8'), { format: 'Letter' }).toFile('./Vineet/POC/PDF_Outputs/Output.pdf', function(err, res) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you Answer.I already Installed Phantom.js using the following command - "npm install phantomjs -g". Even After that I am getting this error.Do I need to set the class path for Phantom.js or do any other configurational setting

Comment: download phantomjs http://phantomjs.org/download.html and config PATH as this document http://phantomjs.org/build.html

Comment: I tried this but still getting the same exception :(

Comment: Can Any One please help me here.

Comment: "Html-Pdf" package is working for me . But I want to use  "html5-to-pdf" package only because in my project We are using HTML5 pages.